# jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget-How to make First item Uncheked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing this JQuery UI multiselect from http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

When I'm trying to validate my single select `dropdownbox`, even if nothing's been selected and the "Please Select" is visible, it still thinks that the first item in the list is the selected one.

`$("#ddlAlternativeCode option:selected").val()` just gets back the value of my first item in the dropdown. `I need it to be 0 or null`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: please provide a fiddle.

Comment: Provide the html/js code

Comment: first option is always gets selected.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write "option:selected" in the $("#ddlAlternativeCode option:selected").val()

Try this instead:

```
$("#ddlAlternativeCode").val();
```

You should be able to see it working by adding this following alert which should show NULL if nothing is selected:

```
alert("value= "+$('#ddlAlternativeCode').val());
```

where the id is the id of the selector.
If that doesn't work, your javascript has an error somewhere.

The other way of collecting selected values with Eric's script is via the "GetChecked" method call on the API.  See example here:

```
var array_of_checked_values = $("select").multiselect("getChecked").map(function(){
   return this.value;    
}).get();
```